# Is there any Kafka connector which integrates with REST API and writes data to kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a requirement in my project where I have to get the data after hitting a REST service. Is there any Kafka connector that does this work or I have to write the custom code using streams or producer ?
I tried finding REST connector on ( https://www.confluent.io/hub/ ) but could not find anything. Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're asking for the HTTP Sink Connector, which does exist on that page.

There is also a `kafka-connect-rest` project on Github

Comment: thank you for your reply but I am looking for connector which integrates with REST API and write the data received to kafka topic. HTTP sink connector does reverse of it and kafka-connect-rest is used for some other purpose i.e. for defining and maintaining connector bit. 
I had found Kafka Connect Http after you mentioned HTTP sink but I am not sure whether it will serve my purpose or not. So I am looking into it now.

Comment: kafka-connect-http connector

Comment: I was able to hit the API using this connector but I don't think this connector support the following thing:

As per our architecture, each of our API needs an access token to hit the API. This means that I have to first hit the security API which gives me access token and then the main API which gives me data back.

For eg:

1. Hit https:///security-api/api (This gives me back access token)
2. Hit the Resource API https:///customers (Have to pass access token from the first API into header of this API)
So I think we need to write a separate producer or streams app for it

Comment: In that case, I would suggest something like NiFi or Streamsets as a higher level orchestrator.

Comment: This is the basic need to have access token to access the REST API as most of the organisation's support this as a security layer to their API. The connector should support this. I am not sure where to raise this in confluent or kafka if they can look into this issue.

Comment: Apache Kafka itself doesn't have an HTTP connector, and I'm not sure if Confluent really supports non-enterprise customers (within a given timeline, at least). Connect API is open source; you can write your own

Comment: @aggarwalb Maybe this is promising?  https://github.com/castorm/kafka-connect-http/issues/42

Comment: thanks @PatrickSzalapski The link you shared was raised by myself only